# Comparar Response com variável

Tags: javascript

Eu fiz uma variável de ambiente que pega o ID de uma Conta cadastrada, e quando eu vou no meu método Buscar ID estou validando pra ver se trouxe o que eu estou esperando passando o `code:8631` como Request.

O retorno do meu método mostra o código sendo `8631`. A minha variável de ambiente `idConta` também possui o valor `8631`. Porém esta dando erro, fala que o número não é igual ao outro, já tentei com `pm.expect` também e nada.

```js
let responseJson = JSON.parse(responseBody);
    
pm.test("deve retornar um elemento", function() {  
    if (responseJson.code === "{{idConta}}") {  
        pm.response.to.be.ok;  
    } else {  
        pm.response.to.be.error;  
});
```

Comment: O tipo de dado retornado é o mesmo que você compara na condição?

Answer (score -1):

Se seu retorno é o esperado, é bem provável que o problema esteja no tipo de dado retornado/comparado na condição.

No `JavaScript`, como os tipos das variáveis nem sempre são levados em consideração, existem duas opções: o operador == (e o mesmo vale para o operador !=), que não leva em consideração o tipo de dados; e o operador === (e também !==), que considera o tipo de dados, o que possibilita afirmar que os valores são, de fato, iguais. Exemplo:

```
var verdadeiro = '1' == 1;
var falso = '1' === 1;
```

Para testes, você pode verificar o tipo de dado com a função `typeof`.

```
console.log(typeof(responseJson.code));
```

Assim você pode tanto mudar o tipo de retorno, fazer um casting na própria condição, ou simplesmente mudar a condição para forma que não se aplique a comparação do tipo.

Answer (score -1):

O problema está nesta linha :

```
if (responseJson.code === "{{idConta}}") {
```

Note que o {{idConta}} está entre aspas, mas deveria estar entre ``, do modo que você fez, está comparando uma string que é idêntica a "{{idConta}}", não ao número que você salvou na variável. Inclusive, você colocou entre couchetes, que também devem ser desnecessários nesse caso.Sei que a pergunta é antiga, mas talvez ajude alguém que tenha cometido esse erro também.